# How to compare two columns values in the same table PowerBI DAX

Tags: powerbi, data-analysis, dax

I am working in a data analysis project using MS Power BI, thankfully I'm doing good work to start. However, I'm facing a little problem with DAX syntax. I come from a web development background. Anyways, my current problem is that I have rental vehicles, which can be rented from one branch and handed in at another.

I would like to compare two columns values in the same table. 'owner_branch' and 'current_branch'. Is it a good choice to create a filter with DAX? Or should I move to R Language?

Comment: How can I compare both two columns values in the same row? something like a loop  for example or a kind of join in SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your problem correct you need Calculated Column like this:

```
CompCol = IF ( Owner_Branch = Current_Branch, TRUE, FALSE )
```

Comment: This is what I have done, but isn't there any better way to resolve the problem ?

Comment: As far as I know it is the best way to do this. What you can do to make it more efficient  is to search for a DAX function that returns result of comparison instead of using IF clause but probably there is no better way than Calculated Column which you have to remember is evaluated at the beginning. You can add custom column if you don't want do calculated column. Formula for custom column will look something like this. if [col1] = [col2] then true else false

Answer (score 1):

as a temporary solution which I think that is not an efficient solution for a larger records in future. Anyways, my solution was creating a new column type of boolean.

Comment: Just curious, why do you think the above solution is inefficient?